# Implementing own oembed provider - how to test?

Tags: oembed, video-embedding

I have created a video streaming site, so thought I'd try to implement my own oembed provider for this site.  After reading the oembed specs and testing you tube and vimeo's own oembed endpoints I have implemented one for my site.

Now as far as I can tell it follows the spec exactly, but I can't work out how to properly test it.  Does anyone know of an oembed provider testing suite?

Answer (score 1):

We have faced the same problem. The only way we found to test our oEmbed provider is embed.ly website, where you can paste your url.